# Are OAuth access tokens user specific?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, dotnet-httpclient

We need to add new functionality to our web app, which is written in **asp.net core 3.1** and **angular**, which creates new scheduled meetings in **Zoom** (the video conferencing services provider). Currently this is the only requirement, so on the face of it it sounds simple. And indeed their api is well documented and easy to use. Now, since we're using **asp.net core** on the server, we can use its caching capabilities, like session, in memory chaching (**IMemoryCache**) etc. The piece of knowledge that i am missing to complete the picture is about **OAuth** access tokens. I'm not sure whether an access token that is issued by **Zoom** is specific for the user that has just been authenticated/authorized and wants to create a new meeting or for our web app (let's call our web app the client, by **OAuth**'s terms). So the meaning of this is that we need to choose the right storage mechanism for access tokens. If it's at the user level, ie specific to the user of our app currently using it, we need to store the token in **asp.net core**'s Session storage, but on the other hand if the token is, let's say one level above we need to store the token globally, maybe in the memory caching of asp.net core, the **IMemoryCahce** stuff. This is the main issue i need to understand. Regarding keeping the access token on the server, that is the best practice as far as i have understood from reading some material on the subject.

Thank you very much,
ashilon

Comment: by OAuth's terms, `client` is your user's browser, so maybe store them within your angular app?

Comment: According to several resources on the internet this is not recommended. One example: https://medium.com/@benjamin.botto/secure-access-token-storage-with-single-page-applications-part-1-9536b0021321

Comment: I'm not talking about persisting it in browser's `Local Storage`. Store it in memory.

Comment: Oh, I get it now, your `asp.net core API` need to do something with `Zoom` on the user’s behalf. That's why you call it a `client`.

Comment: Looks like you need to use auth code flow with pkce or implicit flow of oauth grant types. Once the user logs in your app, you need to store the jwt token intended for zoom on user's behalf in the browser storage. Then when you make api calls, you need to pass that token to your then in turn to zoom. Here, you are using delegated permissions where user has consented the app to do something in zoom in his/her behalf.

Comment: To answer your question, assuming the authorization code flow is being used, yes the access token is specific to a user

Comment: @Randy If you post your comment as an answer I can set it as accepted answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, assuming the authorization code flow is being used, yes the access token is specific to a user. This is because the token is the result of an authentication performed by an individual user within the 3rd party OAuth provider.

[Although client access tokens are a concept within the OAuth specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.4), 3rd party user-facing applications typically don't give wide-ranging permissions and stick to a user-by-user basis (not even supporting the client_credentials grant).